# Electric field of semi-sphere

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, mathematical-physics

I have to find the electrical field in the center (of the base) of a semi spherical shell of radius R. The total charge Q (Q > 0) is uniform on the intern surface of the semi sphere. Here's a scheme:

[image]

And here's the solution:

[image]

I found the first equality ($E_{z}$ = the first integral), but then I was stuck to integrate other the intern surface of the semi-sphere.

Could someone explain me how it's done? I don't get the second equality.

Many thanks,

Comment: Do you know how to do surface integrals? This is what happened here. He used spherical coordinates.

Comment: $\text d\sigma = R^2\sin\theta\text d\theta\text d\phi$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go through this step by step:

The electric field point away from a single charge q distance r away is:
$E = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}}\frac{Q}{R^2}$

However since we are dealing with charge spread over a hemisphere we must integrate over the surface charge density $\sigma_{q} = \frac{Q}{2\pi R^2}$ Furthermore, we know that charges opposite each other will cancel, so we must times put $cos(\theta)$ in the integral

So we have:
$$E = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}R^2}\iint_{S(A)} cos(\theta)\frac{Q}{2\pi R^2}dA = \frac{Q}{8\pi^2\epsilon_{0}R^4}\iint_{S(A)}\cos(\theta)dA$$

We then decompose the surface integral into two regular itegrals.

Quantitatively this is expressed in spherical coordinates as $dA = R^2sin(\theta)d\theta d\phi$

Alternatively it can be thought of qualitatively as a surface of revolution using spherical cordinates as described below:

We first integrate a quarter circle $\theta$ from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, then we take that quarter circle and integrate a surface of revolution around the z axis with $\phi$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ which is just $2\pi$. Since the distance ("height") of the surface from z is given by $sin(\theta)$ we multiply by that in the integral as well (because the "lower" it is the less it will revolve). This sine term goes in the second integral, not the first, **a)** because it is also a function of theta and **b)** because if put $sin(\phi)$ in the first integral the answer would be zero. Since the surface of the sphere scales with $R^2$ we must also times multiply our answer by that.

Hence either way we have:

$$E = \frac{Q}{8\pi^2\epsilon_{0}R^4}R^2\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin(\theta)cos(\theta)d\theta d\phi = \frac{Q}{8\pi\epsilon_{0}R^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $Q$ is uniform, the charge differential $dq$ is given by $$dq = \frac{Q}{\text{Area}(\Sigma)}d\sigma = \frac{Q}{2\pi R^2}d\sigma.$$ Thus $$dE_z = dE\cos\theta = \frac{1}{4\pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{dq}{r^2}\cos\theta = \frac{1}{4\pi \varepsilon_0} \frac{Q}{2\pi R^2}\frac{d\sigma}{R^2}\cos\theta.$$ Now we can write $$E_z = \int_{\Sigma} dE_z = \frac{1}{4\pi \varepsilon_0}\int_\Sigma \frac{Q}{2\pi R^2}\frac{d\sigma}{R^2}\cos\theta.$$ In spherical coordinates, $d\sigma = R^2\sin \theta\, d\theta\, d\phi$. Since $\phi$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$ and $\theta$ ranges from $0$ to $\pi/2$, we have $$\frac{1}{4\pi \varepsilon_0} \int_\Sigma \frac{Q}{2\pi R^2}\frac{d\sigma}{R^2}\cos\theta = \frac{Q}{8\pi^2\varepsilon_0 R^2} \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin\theta \cos\theta\, d\theta.$$